# While searching in google, the search results showcasing custom template tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-search, ecmascript-5, google-search-console

[While searching in google, the search results showcasing custom template tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o313v.png)

Please click the above link,---- while i am searching, my custom template tag to highlight query in search results.

Comment: the web site is working in vuejs and i think I need to add meta tags like <meta name='description' content='blahblahblah'>...more information please...

Comment: Google is not executing the JavaScript on your page. It just reads the template tags as you have them in the HTML. This is the reason some projects using UI frameworks implement "server-side rendering."  For Vue see: https://ssr.vuejs.org/